# VBA - Replace Date and Time as Day of Week and AM/PM

Tags: vba, excel, date, time

I was wondering if there is a way to change the mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm into for the first part either Mon, Tues, Wed, etc. and for the second part AM or PM.  For Example, `"12/26/2016 7:29"` to be `"Monday"` in a separate cell and `"AM"` in another separate cell.

I am unsure if using a `Replace` function would be useful or if there is something else more useful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: custom number format of `dddd` and AM/PM` in another cell.

Comment: @Jeeped - So, copy the cell into two other cells and change the format?

Comment: @ACohen I believe so, and the second column's format should be `AM/PM`

Comment: Or use the formula TEXT() in other cells with the proper format string.

Comment: with `12/26/2016 7:29` in A1 put `=a1` in B1 and cnf (ctrl+1) as `dddd`. In C1 with `=a1` and cnf as `AM/PM`

Comment: @Jeeped - Do you mind putting this in an answer format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each of your requirements can be met with a custom number format.

With `12/26/2016 7:29` in A1 put `=a1` in B1 and use a cnf (ctrl+1) as `dddd`. In C1 with the same `=a1` formula, use a cnf of `AM/PM`

For VBA, use the .NumberFormat property.

```
range("b1:c1").value = range("a1").value
range("b1").numberformat = "dddd"
range("c1").numberformat = "AM/PM"
```

Answer (score 2):

With data in **A1**, in **B1** enter:

```
=TEXT(A1,"dddd")
```

and in **C1** enter:

```
=RIGHT(TEXT(A1-ROUNDDOWN(A1,0),"[$-F400]h:mm:ss AM/PM"),2)
```

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

Here are some *UDF()'s* to do the same thing:

```
Public Function DayOfWeek(r As Range) As String
    Dim d As Date
    d = r.Value
    DayOfWeek = Format(d, "dddd")
End Function

Public Function PreOrPostNoon(r As Range) As String
    Dim d As Date
    d = r.Value
    PreOrPostNoon = Right(Format(d, "[$-F400]h:mm:ss AM/PM"), 2)
End Function
```

Comment: I am using VBA Format, So this will look somewhat different, correct?

Comment: @ACohen  Do you need VBA UDF()'s ??

Comment: Yes, that will be much appreciated

Comment: @ACohen  See my **EDIT#1**